# Method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to have two seekBars in my app. For this I have two on create commands, but my error is method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity . So I tried to delede one of them but then a lot of commands turn red and say Cannot resolve symbol. How can I use both seekBars with one on create function? 
And maybe I should mention, that the first seekBar worked like a charm before I copy pasted it...

I'm pretty new to programming apps.

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int gas = 0;
int steering = 0;

//Variable Anpassen GAS

private SeekBar seekBarGas;
private TextView textViewGas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

seekBarGas = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGas);
textViewGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGas);
seekBarGas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        textViewGas.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarGas.getMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
   });
}





//Variable Anpassen Steering

private SeekBar seekBarSteering;
private TextView textViewSteering;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBarSteering = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSteering);
    textViewSteering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSteering);
    seekBarSteering.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewSteering.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarSteering.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}



}
```

Comment: Put definition of seekBarSteering and textViewSteering into onCreate method first, and remove the second onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have a duplicate declaration of onCreate method so remove your second on Create method in your activity**

**Code look like this**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int gas = 0;
int steering = 0;

//Variable Anpassen GAS

  private SeekBar seekBarGas;
  private TextView textViewGas;

   private SeekBar seekBarSteering;
   private TextView textViewSteering;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

seekBarGas = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGas);
textViewGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGas);
seekBarGas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    textViewGas.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarGas.getMax());
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
  });

seekBarSteering = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSteering);
textViewSteering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSteering);
seekBarSteering.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        textViewSteering.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarSteering.getMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
}

}
```

**Android activity lifecycle method call once in your activity not twice**

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Thank you i hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you have `onCreate` methdod twice. So, in order that this work you have to remove one of them.

You code should look like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int gas = 0;
int steering = 0;

//Variable Anpassen GAS

private SeekBar seekBarGas;
private TextView textViewGas;

private SeekBar seekBarSteering;
private TextView textViewSteering;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

seekBarGas = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGas);
textViewGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGas);
seekBarGas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        textViewGas.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarGas.getMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
   });

   seekBarSteering = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSteering);
    textViewSteering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSteering);
    seekBarSteering.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewSteering.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarSteering.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

}
```